# Spring - Displaying a Label that reflects and updates a @ModelAttribute field

Tags: java, spring, jstl

I have a `@ModelAttribute` `account` which has a field named `title`. I need to display this field in my JSP, and also bind it in the next call cycle. If I do this;

```
Title: ${editAccountForm.account.title} <br/>
```

It only displays the value. When someone submits the Form in the JSP, `account` is empty again. How do I get the label to reflect the value, just like a `form:input` tag?

I tried this:

```
<form:label path="account.issuer">some text</form:label> <br/>
```

but it dint work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but that is the same to displaying it normally `${editAccountForm.account.title}`. After that, populate the value in a hidden field. that will update the value in the model

Comment: yeah, i figured that out. seems like that's the only way. i even tried `form:input` with `disabled=true` but dint work :(

Answer (score 4):

You can put a

```
<input type="hidden" name="account.title" value="${editAccountForm.account.title}" />
```

The name attribute must be the same as the one generated by a spring form:input.

Comment: That doesn't work. For some reason. It doesn't display anything at all. Besides, I'm trying to use JSTL. Is there a way I can do this with `form:label`?